# Player goes a little bit under the ground after landing

Tags: python, pygame, gravity

Hi I am making a game and I have a problem. When player lands to the ground he goes a little bit under the ground, for example like this:

[image]

And I want someting like this:

[image]

Here is my gravity code:

```
   if not player.player.collidelistall(MAPr) and player.yvel < 4:
       player.yvel -= 0.3
   if player.player.collidelistall(MAPr):
       player.yvel = 0
   player.y -= player.yvel
   cy -= player.yvel
```

thanks!

Comment: You have two options: change the position after the collision has happened and move the player outside the collision object OR determine upcoming collisions beforehand, only run a partial physics step until the collision happens, handle the collision (e.g. set the velocity to 0) and then continue with the physics step until the next collision. Currently you are reacting to the collision not as the collision happens but significantly after it has *happened*, something that would not occur in the real world.

Answer (score 0):

Calculate the player's position as it would be if it had moved before the collision test. Only move the player if it doesn't collide. Set the player's position on the ground when you detect the collision:

```py
player.y = cy - player.yvel
indices = player.player.collidelistall(MAPr)

if indices:
    player.yvel = 0
    for i in indices:
        player.player.bottom = MAPr[i].top
    cy = player.player.y 
else:
    cy -= player.yvel
    if player.yvel < 4:
        player.yvel -= 0.3
```

See [`collidelistall`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html#pygame.Rect.collidelistall):

> Returns a list of all the indices that contain rectangles that collide with the Rect